# Where is the reference created from code ⇒ IL or IL ⇒ native code

Tags: c#, constructor, reference

I'm struggling to find where will the reference be created for an object and at which phase it will be created **From Program to Intermediate Code** or **Intermediate Code to Native Code**.

Comment: When you compile your code, you get IL. There is no program code anymore.

Comment: At what stage will the reference of an object say `MyClass myClass = new MyClass()` is created. I can't see the reference in [ILDASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler)

Comment: A reference of an object is only valid when the program runs (a physical address in the memory). So you can only see its information when you attach a debugger to a live process, but not statically in tools like ILDASM or ILSpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article might help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/):

> Typically, apps that target the .NET Framework are compiled to intermediate language (IL). At run time, the just-in-time (JIT) compiler translates the IL to native code. In contrast, .NET Native compiles Windows apps directly to native code.

So, as you see, IL is not even a prerequisite, it can be omitted fully (though in most cases, it shouldn't)

[As mentioned in the CLR guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr):

> The runtime automatically handles object layout and manages references to objects, releasing them when they are no longer being used. Objects whose lifetimes are managed in this way are called managed data. Garbage collection eliminates memory leaks as well as some other common programming errors.

So since the executed code is turned into native code before running and the objects are created then I think it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are actually created in runtime, your code is merely the instructions for it to be created, your code will be compiled to **IL** when you compile it.

The runtime then (**JIT compiler**) will interpret this code to native code, anyway this all isn't actually creating your objects. the objects and the references of it will be created just when the CPU executes the interpreted code and stores some value in the memory.